# Change optionality of generic object's keys based on an array of keys in TypeScript

Tags: arrays, typescript, object, generics

**Background:**

I'm using a backend library to convert database models into their respective TypeScript type definitions. The model objects can have relations (joined tables) that can be loaded by the backend, but they're not set unless the relation was loaded, hence the TypeScript definition considers the types of relations as optional.

I want to create a piece of validation code that can help me spot potential errors by throwing an error if one of the relations that I need in the front-end is undefined (hasn't been loaded). The data that comes back from this validation function should be the model object with the validated relations no longer being optional (since their presence was confirmed by the validation).

**Code:**

Here's the very simply validation code I made:

```
export function requireRelationships<Model extends object>(model: Model, keys: Array<keyof Model>) {

  const errors = [] as Array<string>;

  keys.forEach(key => {
    if(model[key] === undefined) {
      errors.push(`Required relation '${key as string} not loaded.`)
    }
  })

  if(errors.length > 0) {
    throw new Error(errors.join("\n"))
  }
  
  return model as Pick<Required<Model>, typeof keys[number]>
}
```

Here's a simplified example of how I'm using it:

```
interface Model {
    posts?: string[],
    comments?: string[],
    id: string;
    title?: string;
    age?: number;
}

declare const modelFromBackend: Model;
modelFromBackend.posts.length; // error, possibly undefined
modelFromBackend.title.length; // error, possibly undefined

const validatedModel = requireRelationships(modelFromBackend, ['posts', 'comments']);
validatedModel.posts.length; // should be okay
validatedModel.title.length; // should still be error, possibly undefined
```

**Question:**

**How do I define a type that is the same as the given generic `Model` type but with the keys that were provided by the `keys` array being set as no longer optional?**

My current code just returns the model with **all** keys being set as non-optional, even the ones that were not validated. Using `typeof keys[number]` is not very helpful since `keyof Model` is just an union of all keys regardless of what's in the `keys` array and thus can't be used for any sort of filtering. I also tried to create some sort of constant union typing from the array but that doesn't work because even if `keys` is an array containing string literals (that are defined before runtime), the function doesn't seem to be able to utilize that information.

Comment: Quite possibly you want [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mL3zaN) but without a [mre] (e.g., what's `modelFromBackend`) it's hard to be sure.  Ideally you'd show at least one example that demonstrates an expected input-output relationship.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks, after a quick test, that seems to do exactly what I was after. Can you copy the code from the playground link and convert the comment into an answer so I can accept it as a solution?

Comment: Okay, I did so; do you mind if I [edit] your question to copy the example from my answer up into the question so that it's a [mre]?

Comment: @jcalz No problem. I avoided including my model data in the example simply because it's rather large. There's nothing special about the models however as they're just plain objects so a minimal example should illustrate the functionality just as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the output of `requireRelationships()` to depend on the particular keys passed in for the `keys` argument, then you need to make the function [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the type of those keys. For example:

```
declare function requireRelationships<T extends object, K extends keyof T>(
    model: T, keys: Array<K>
): T & Pick<Required<T>, K>;
```

Here `K` is a generic type parameter [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to be some set of keys of `T`.  When you call the function, the compiler will infer `T` to be the type of the `model` argument, and `K` to be the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of the elements in the array passed in as the `keys` argument.

The output type is [the intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of `T` with `Pick<Required<T>, K>`, using the [`Pick`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys) and [`Required`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#requiredtype) utility types to describe a type which has all the properties from `T`, and additionally those mentioned in `K` are required.

---

Let's test it out:

```
interface Model {
    posts?: string[],
    comments?: string[],
    id: string;
    title?: string;
    age?: number;
}
declare const modelFromBackend: Model;
modelFromBackend.posts.length; // error, possibly undefined
modelFromBackend.title.length; // error, possibly undefined

const validatedModel = requireRelationships(modelFromBackend, ['posts', 'comments']);
// const validatedModel: Model & Pick<Required<Model>, "posts" | "comments">
validatedModel.posts.length; // okay
validatedModel.title.length; // error, possibly undefined
```

Looks good.  `validatedModel` is known to contained defined `posts` and `comments` properties, while the other properties from `Model` are unaffected.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXzgEdks4AlEabPAZwAssAHGgHgBV4QAPDEVYGvBwAjAFbgMAGngBpTjz4D4AaxABPHInhsAfAAoAUPGPwAtjlAQAXNumq1NGwEEYMKGpYydBgJQ2OAGTwAApYYMosFMSkIMDsOtJeANwGBliovDCIUGAIALIWlPAA3kYmjDg0GDQA-DZVMOkA5gDaALqSZcZgOKamfNV18A3N7Z0m8FjA9RiNqE0pE9gYECBDI-OLJlBNazaoyKbCIDApAL4GoJCwCD2oVWaFEABiML0AQjmq-DYFlinmSyvD5fRQAOgqVRoYNW8wwdCS8AA9EjOK4cDBpJCaFhhBA1PA0KBEOlYgZAZRgaZPuFwctVjC+E14YiUWi3pj4NjcfjCfwQCTUGS7g8AG5QCBTKC8YB-IoAXgIIGi5Eo0tw9wYzD0FJeb2poP40haAHJIdUTdITT0+gMaCa2j4UmyRRh4OLJcBpbE5dZ4L74EFQuFIsqSHA4r6EvAAETmmgx+AAH1jNv6GQT3g9UplvohlWqjLhCORqJwyncBmzXtzTzB9JAReZJbZJw5WMqOLxBKJAtJwCAA)

Comment: I would add that because you aren't returning a new object, consider using type guards instead.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html